# Best place to add a navigation bar button?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uikit

Where should I place my code that creates a `UIBarButtonItem` and assigns it to `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem`? In `initWithNibName` or `viewDidLoad`?

EDIT: I should clarify that I'm loading a NIB from Interface Builder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`viewDidLoad` is the correct place to create the button programatically whether you are loading a NIB from Interface Builder or not.

From the `UIViewController` class, `viewDidLoad` method documentation

> This method is called after the view controller has loaded its
>   associated views into memory. This method is called regardless of
>   whether the views were stored in a nib file or created
>   programmatically in the loadView method. This method is most commonly
>   used to perform additional initialization steps on views that are
>   loaded from nib files.

Comment: Can you point out to me why one should not load the button in loadView?

Comment: you can, it's just that the OP makes reference to the `initWithNibName:bundle` method so they must be using Interface Builder to load their main view. 'loadView' is only used when you are creating the entire view structure programatically.

Answer (score 0):

In `- (void) loadView` if you do it pragmatically. Otherwise do as Rog suggests.

Comment: It's in viewDidLoad right now, but I don't see any animation. Maybe it's too fast too see?

Comment: if you want to see the animation, load it up in `viewDidAppear` instead but make sure you unload it on `viewWillDisappear` or `viewDidDisappear` if you want it to animate everytime the view is displayed.

Comment: @Wolfert `loadView` is only called if the entire view structure is being created programatically (i.e. no interface builder is being used).

Comment: Sorry confused it with UINavigationItem which can be added animated:.

Comment: @Wolfert: The documentation says that I must not override loadView "if you use Interface Builder to create your views and initialize the view controller".